# Using Custom data type in QT TreeModel

Tags: qt, qt5

This is my Container class defination

```
class Container
{
private:
      std::string stdstrContainerName;
      std::string stdstrPluginType;
      std::string stdstrPluginName;
      int iSegments;
      float fRadius;
public:
    Container();
    explicit Container(std::string strContainerName , std::string 
    strPluginName , std::string strPluginType, int segments , float 
     radius  );
  ~Container();
  std::string GetName();
  std::string GetType();
   void SetName(std::string stdstrName);
};
```

I want the nodes of the TreeView to hold object of Container class as data.

This is the header file for the TreeItem class.

```
 class TreeItem
  {
  public:
    explicit TreeItem( const Container &data , TreeItem *parent = 0 );
   ~TreeItem();
    TreeItem *parent();
    TreeItem *child(int iNumber);
    int childCount() const;
    int childNumber() const;
    Container data() const;
    bool setData(const Container &data);
    bool insertChildren(int position, int count );
    bool removeChildren( int position  , int count );
private:
   QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
   Container itemData;
   TreeItem* parentItem;
};
```

The problem i am facing is while implementing the TreeModel functions.
how can i use Container as the data type instead of QVariant.

```
     QVariant data(const QModelIndex &undex, int role) const override;
     QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
     int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
     bool setData( const QModelIndex &index , const QVariant &value , int 
     role = Qt::EditRole) override;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Container` *instead of* `QVariant`, but you can use `Container` *inside a* `QVariant`. Have a look at [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE).

Add it in the header file after the declaration of `Container`:

```
class Container
{
private:
    // ...
public:
    Container();
    // ...
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Container); // You only need this once, so here is a good place
```

When you created the `Container` meta type, you can return it like this:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override {
    TreeItem *item = ...;
    return QVariant::fromValue(item->data());
}
```

And in your view you retrieve the `Container` like this:

```
QVariant v = model()->data(index, role);
Container c = v.value<Container>();
```

---

Beware that this only works within the same thread, else you'd need to register `Container` with `qRegisterMetaType()` and maybe even write a converter function from / to `QVariant`.
This doesn't apply to your situation, though, because model and view are not designed to live in different threads.